# Blue veins appearing on legs

Tags: stress, age, varicose-veins, legs, standing

Lately blue veins started appearing on my girlfriend's legs. She is 21 years old, she works in a flowers factory where she has to stand for around 8 hours on same spot and boxing flowers or whatever.

The blue veins started appearing once she started working, she is stressed most of time, her body always tired from standing. It even increased once she moved from a country to another after vacation.. Oh also she has compression socks and pantyhose if that's what it is called.

What I would like to know, is this normal for a 21 years old female? Could it be by birth? Is it work? or just being stressed can cause this?

Here are 2 pictures of her leg:
[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: Those simply look like normal veins. And yes, standing does increase that but it's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Aha so it doesn't mean that there are "problems"? That's good to hear. To be honest we both were worried that her like skin or veins are going "wrong".. thank you.

Comment: Wait until you get a full answer on here, and if you're still concerned, go to a doctor. But no, I don't think there are any issues here

Comment: Hopefully there will not be a full answer since this is a request for personal medical advice, which nobody should be answering. That said, yeah, those are perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1):

Veins pop out when the muscles are strained.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-do-veins-pop-out-when/

Muscle builders try to get them popping out with constraining the blood flow by tying something to their arms. The compression socks and pantyhose may work in a similar way.

http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Veins-to-Pop-Out

Comment: Why do you answer the question if you agree with Carey's comment? He explicitly stated that no-one should answer...

Comment: @Narusan because he is only kind of right. For a medical consulting no answer should be given, but in the set of questions OP asks, it makes sense to give other kind of answers. In a comment you cannot share as much information. I then made an answer that tells that popping veins is normal, how it happens and that some even seek out such an effect. I then also pointed out that it can be something else because proper medical consulting should be done by a doctor because there is a possibility that it can be something worse and then just stating that it is normal is a bit bad comment/answer.

Comment: Then maybe state that in the beginning of your answer? This's would be less confusing for readers

Comment: @Narusan that has no role in the factual part of the message that veins pop-out in stressed muscles and that compressing increases the effect. I think that it would be worth of a meta discussion if the health SE should have a warning sign: "Please consult your doctor not SE, if you feel that something is wrong in your or your acquaintance's body." In that way, it would not need to be reminded that it can always be something else because the veins can also be a symptom of some decease.

Comment: Actually I noticed that there is a warning sign, so I removed the rest of the answer.